# Using intent broadcast USER_PRESENT in Android O

Tags: android

Since O is more enforcing background services, how can I receive a broadcast of USER_PRESENT when targeting 26+ ?

Logcat :

```
system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT flg=0x24200010 } to fr.cab13140.nullcontactdeleter/.BootThread
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to receive that broadcast is by having a running process, where you have used `registerReceiver()` to register your receiver. If you are trying to listen to this broadcast all of the time, the closest that you will get will be to have a foreground sticky service, to try to maximize the amount of time your service is running. Note that users may not appreciate this.

Comment: So, using this approach is impossible. How about BOOT_COMPLETED ? I'm not receiving the intent nor the logcat error.

Comment: @cab13140: Hmmm... `BOOT_COMPLETED` is supposed to work, and IIRC I tried it and it worked.

Comment: I will give it a try one more time. I'm using a Log.d but nothing shows up.

Comment: @cab13140: As with prior versions of Android, make sure that you have launched your main activity or something before rebooting, to move the app out of the stopped state.

Comment: That might be the thing. I remember you need to boot at least once the app

Comment: @CommonsWare it seems true, but do you have any official notice about that, I checked in https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT but didn't see any relevant

Comment: @thanhbinh84: See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts

Comment: What if we simply want to update a widget once user is present again? We need a foreground sticky service for that, or is there already a better way?

Comment: @PrimožKralj: I would argue that it is the job of the home screen implementation to ask for updates at that point in time, as the home screen should know when it is displayed again.