# How to receive broadcast when user unlock phone in Oreo if App is in background

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

On PreOreo devices, I implement broadcast receiver for listening user unlocks . I am using a service for this.

```
  public class UserUnlockService extends Service {
    public UserUnlockService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        registerReceiver(new UserUnlockBroadcastReceiver(),filter);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

This solution works perfectly on PreOreo devices and and its works on Oreo device if my app is in foreground. When app is in background this service won't work. I know that in Oreo we can't run background services. I tried Most of the SO answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996560/how-to-run-a-background-service-in-oreo-for-longer-period) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270691/permanent-services-on-android-oreo) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827592/using-intent-broadcast-user-present-in-android-o)

And I  tried this [article](https://medium.com/@berriz_/service-and-boot-completed-on-android-o-6a389eae50f1) but it doesn't help me

I am also tried foreground services. but showing notification all the time is not good for my app's UX.

So my question is how can I receive USER_PRESENT broadcast in Oreo if app is in background.
Is there any workaround solution for this?

Or how other popular apps achieves long running services in Oreo devices?

Comment: "but showing notification all the time is not good for my app's UX" -- that decision is up to the user, not you.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any other  way without the notification. I only want to Listen  user unlock (USER_PRESENT)

Comment: `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` does not appear on [the implicit broadcast exception whitelist](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions). That whitelist is not completely accurate, so you could just try a manifest-registered receiver and see if it works. But, if that does not work, then AFAIK a foreground service is your only option.

Comment: I tried manifest-registered receiver. It won't trigger. the only thing working is the foreground service.

Comment: @VinayakB My App, targeting lower than Oreo worked fine and triggers were working. But when I make it target Oreo, the user_present broadcast stopped. I am showing a notification with the service. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @kirtan403  No. I didn't. I am using foreground notification for now